# Advice needed for a problem from Advanced Calculus by Patrick M. Fitzpatrick

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, $g(0)>0$ and there exists $x_o >0$ such that $g(x_o)=0.$ Prove there is a smallest positive number $p$ at which $g(x)=0.$

May I verify if my proof is correct? Thank you.

Proof:  Let $A=\{x:x>0, g(x)=0\}.$ Since $A \neq \emptyset$ and $0<x, \forall x\in A, \ p= \text{inf} \ A$ exists.

If $p <0,$ then given $\ 0-p,\ $there exist $x \in A$ such that $x<p+(0-p)=0.$ (Contradiction)

Now, since $g(0) >0, \exists \delta >0$ such that $g(x) >0, \forall x \in (-\delta, \delta).$

If $p=0,$ then given $\delta >0,$ there exists $w \in A$ such that $0+\delta >w$.  (Contradiction)

Hence $p>0.$

Given $\frac{1}{i}, \exists x_i \in A$ such that $p+\frac{1}{i} >x_i >p.\ $ Hence $\{x_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \to p.$ So $g(p) =  \lim_{n \to \infty} g(x_n) =0.$

Comment: How did it follow that if $p<0$, then $0\in A$?

Comment: Thanks for your instruction. I have amended accordingly.

Comment: The fact that the sequence is strictly decreasing is not enough to show that it converges to $0$. Imagine you have $x_i=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{i}$.

Comment: Thank you, what would be your suggested approach ?

Comment: I would take a sequence that I know converges to $0$, e.g. $\frac{1}{n}$. If $p=0$, then for any $n$, there exists an element $x_n\in A$, such that $p+\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}>x_n$.

Comment: There's no need to argue the case $p<0$.  Since $x>0$ for all $x\in A$, $\inf A\ge 0$.

Comment: Noted. I have amended accordingly.

Comment: I do not see a proof that $g(p)=0$.

Comment: This missing proof is just continuity at $p=\lim x_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $g$ is continuous the set $\{x\in{\mathbb R}\>|\>g(x)\ne0\}$ is open, and its complement $A:=\{x\in{\mathbb R}\>|\>g(x)=0\}$ is closed. It follows that the set $K:=A\cap[0,x_0]$ is compact, and as it is nonempty it has a minimal element.

For a more pedestrian proof consider the set
$$B:=\{x\in{\mathbb R}\>|\>x\geq 0, \ g(x)\leq0\}\ .$$
This set is nonempty and bounded below; therefore it has an infimum $p:=\inf B$. I claim that $g(p)=0$, which then implies that $p$ is  the smallest positive $x$ with $g(x)=0$.

*Proof.* (Note that your proof of $g(p)=0$ is somewhat fishy.) If $g(p)<0$ then there is a full neighborhood $U$ of $p$ with $g(x)<0$ for all $x\in U$, contradicting the definition of $p$. Similarly, if $g(p)>0$  then there is a full neighborhood $U$ of $p$ with $g(x)>0$ for all $x\in U$. This means that there are numbers $p'>p$ which can serve as lower bounds for $B$ – again contradicting the definition of $p$.

Comment: Very nice. +1 Yet the topological flavour may be off the OP's level.